# how to make auto flash in custom imagepicker view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `LLSimple` camera within custom overlay in `imagepickerview controller`. I have added flash on/off when I toggle. I want to put auto flash functionality. Plz help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [self.imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self.imagePickerController setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
........
```

explicitly mention

```
[imagePickerController setCameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn];
```

If you don't then the camera defaults to `UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto`
and since the logic you've implemented doesn't handle this case, it remains in `UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto`